DbDataAdapter.Fill crashes internally with NullReferenceException
Basically, when I'm trying to get data from db by calling DbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
very rarely, this call just crashes internally with NullReferenceException.
I hooked a symbols to try to debug what went wrong, and so I found it crashed at line 3833 in DataTable.cs inside RecordStateChanged method.
internal void RecordStateChanged(int record1, DataViewRowState oldState1, DataViewRowState newState1,
                                 int record2, DataViewRowState oldState2, DataViewRowState newState2)
{
    SetShadowIndexes();
    try
    {
        int numIndexes = _shadowIndexes!.Count; // <---- ! Exception is thrown here
        for (int i = 0; i < numIndexes; i++)
        {
            Index ndx = _shadowIndexes[i]; // shadowindexes may change, see ShadowIndexCopy()
            if (0 < ndx.RefCount)
            {
                if (record1 != -1 && record2 != -1)
                {
                    ndx.RecordStateChanged(record1, oldState1, newState1, record2, oldState2, newState2);
                }
                else if (record1 != -1)
                {
                    ndx.RecordStateChanged(record1, oldState1, newState1);
                }
                else if (record2 != -1)
                {
                    ndx.RecordStateChanged(record2, oldState2, newState2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        RestoreShadowIndexes();
    }
    // System.Data.XML.Store.Store.OnROMChanged(record1, oldState1, newState1, record2, oldState2, newState2);
}

As I found out, List<Index> _shadowIndexes was null, if to believe this code, SetShadowIndexes() failed, obviously, so I looked into it:
private void SetShadowIndexes()
{
    if (null == _shadowIndexes)
    {
        Debug.Assert(0 == _shadowCount, "unexpected count");
        _shadowIndexes = LiveIndexes;
        _shadowCount = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Assert(1 <= _shadowCount, "unexpected negative shadow count");
        _shadowCount++;
    }
}

Here, if _shadowIndexes is not null, it will increment internal count and exit, otherwise it will assign it to LiveIndexes and exit, so single possible path of _shadowIndexes being null is by LiveIndexes being null.
But when program was stopped at breakpoint at _shadowIndexes!.Count; line, i looked at LiveIndexes and it wasn't null, it was a list with 1 item in it.
So, dead end, it seems? _shadowIndexes became null after it was assigned to a list that is not null. Have anyone else experienced this kind of behavior?
